# Cloned IDs using joins in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I have a table as below:

[image]

In this table, for the same CID, CVID is cloned multiple times. So for the latest CVID, I want to show the oldest Date. My desired output should be:

[image]

Rextester link: http://rextester.com/ENVH45805

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `row_nunmber` window function to assign a number to each row in the same `cvid` and then take the first one:

```
SELECT cid, cvid, cloned_cvid, _date
FROM   (SELECT cid, cvid, cloned_cvid, _date, 
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY cvid ORDER BY _date ASC) AS rn
        FROM   #temp1) t
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked!